# Openshift Jenkins deployment location

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have a webservice hosted at openshift along with a Jenkins setup. I want a jenkins build to happen for each push. My question is;

do I push to myapp? or push to jenkins?

For instance I would like for the whole codebase to be on jenkins git, and then be able to deploy war files into the webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just push to your app's remote repo (while the Jenkins is enabled for that app). The Jenkins server does not store the code base, it will just create a temporary gear to copy the code over and to build the app. This is described in details [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-continuous-integration.html#how-jenkins-build-works).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, this is indeed the case. It doesn't deploy successful builds (war) to the openshift tomcat7 server though which is a pity.